# In which French city am I?

Tags: visual, emoji

FIRST-LAST-FIRST-FIRST-FIRST-FIRST

In which French city am I?

Comment: Do you mean "In which *French* city am I?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in:

> Paris, France!

> First, line up the words with the emojis. The emojis go in this order: **E**xploding head, tax**I**, **F**ace with tears of joy, **F**ace blowing a kiss, **E**xpressionless face, and **L**ying face. You can extract the word EIFFEL with this, referencing the Eiffel Tower, in Paris, France.